# PHP - Class not found after being included

Tags: php, class, include

I've search the answer about this question , but it doesn't solve my problem.

I have include these class

```
include "class/config.class.php";
include "config/config.php";
include "class/db.mssql.class.php";
```

on my `check_login.php`

and when i tried to login , after i have done type username and password, it does not do anything. Instead it show error when i use firebug .

```
Fatal error: Class 'cfgConn' not found in D:\wamp\www\mapis\config\config.php on line 2
```

this is what `config.php` looks like..

```
<?php
$cfgConn = new cfgConn();

$confMs = $cfgConn->getConf("mssql_configuration");
$dbHostMs     = $confMs['host'];
$dbPortMs     = $confMs['port'];
$dbNameMs     = $confMs['dbName'];
$dbUserMs     = $confMs['user'];
$dbPasswordMs = $confMs['pass'];
```

this is the path of `config.php`

```
D:\wamp\www\mapis\config\config.php
```

I did not see where is the error. The web is fine before i change my WAMP from 2.2 to 2.4, and after that this is what happen.

Note : the `class/config.class.php` was included just fine. it does not show error, instead it show the output at Firebug.

Can anybody show me what is wrong with my code?

Additional :

This is `cfgConn` class defined and the file name is `config.class.php`

```
<?
    class cfgConn
    {
        function getConf($chs)
        {
            switch($chs)
            {
                //SQLServer Connection
                case "mssql_configuration" : {

                            $c['host']   = "IT-KUNTO";
                            $c['dbName'] = "MAP";
                            $c['port']   = "";
                            $c['user']   = "rafi";
                            $c['pass']   = "P@ssw0rd";

                        }break;
            }
            return $c;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need to include the file where the `cfgConn` class is defined ___before___ including your `config.php` file

Comment: Where is the class `cfgConn` ? is it included in some file?

Comment: the `class\config.class.php` is where the `cfgConn` defined and it is called before the `config\config.php` file is called.

Comment: What's this about Firebug? Why Firebug? Shouldn't it show this as a major error on the page itself? Are you by any chance using an AJAX call here?

Comment: Depending on your version of PHP and/or the `short_open_tags` setting in your php.ini, replace `<?` in `config.class.php` with `<?php`

Comment: yes that does the problem, and the version of php is not supporting

Answer (score 0):

In `config.php` file include `config.class.php` like this.

```
<?php
    include "class/config.class.php";
    $cfgConn = new cfgConn();

    $confMs = $cfgConn->getConf("mssql_configuration");
    $dbHostMs     = $confMs['host'];
    $dbPortMs     = $confMs['port'];
    $dbNameMs     = $confMs['dbName'];
    $dbUserMs     = $confMs['user'];
    $dbPasswordMs = $confMs['pass'];
```